# -[__NSArrayI_Transfer objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array"

Tags: ios, swift

getting this error while trying to make onboarding slide

this line is where it crashes

```
            var minItem: NSIndexPath = visibleItems.object(at: 0) as! NSIndexPath
```

```
var sliderArr : [OnBoardingslide] = []
    var currentPage = 0 {
        didSet{
            
            if currentPage == sliderArr.count-1 {
                nextBtn.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
            }
            else{
                nextBtn.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }



 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        registerCollectionView()
        
        let api:OnboardingAPIProtocol = OnboardingAPI()
        api.getOnbooardingSlide { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let slider):
                print("It was successful")
                print(slider!)

                self.sliderArr = slider?.onboardingSlider ?? []


            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }

        }


 @IBAction func nextBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            
        
        if currentPage == sliderArr.count-1 {
            
           homeNav()
        }
        else{
            currentPage += 1
            pageControl.currentPage = currentPage

            let visibleItems: NSArray = self.onBoardingCV.indexPathsForVisibleItems as NSArray

            var minItem: NSIndexPath = visibleItems.object(at: 0) as! NSIndexPath

            for itr in visibleItems {

                if minItem.row > (itr as AnyObject).row {
                    minItem = itr as! NSIndexPath
                }
            }


            let nextItem = NSIndexPath(row: minItem.row + 1, section: 0)
            onBoardingCV.isPagingEnabled = false
            self.onBoardingCV.scrollToItem(at: nextItem as IndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
            onBoardingCV.isPagingEnabled = true

        }


        
    }
    
}
  
        pageControl.numberOfPages = sliderArr.count
  
    }
```

Comment: 1) Don't assume that `visibleItems` has at least 1 item in it. 2) Why are you using `NSArray` and `NSIndexPath`? Use Swift arrays and `IndexPath`.

Comment: When your `onBoardingCV` is not yet got right frame,  `visibleItems.count` may be `0`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.